# how to resolve StandardScaler value error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am following this [image to image search](https://blog.10xai.co/image-to-image-search-using-image-embeddings) tutorial to perform a semantic search over an image dataset. I search multiple SO questions and answers but could pinpoint the solution. This is my code

```
path="../../datasets/101_ObjectCategories"
dest = "content/all_images/"

all_images = [dest+elem for elem in os.listdir(dest)]    #2
print("AMOUNT OF IMAGES :", len(all_images))

# Load as numpy array
dataset = np.empty(shape=(len(all_images),128,128,3)) #1
# print("DATASETS :", dataset)

for i,path in enumerate(all_images):  #2
    img = load_img(path, target_size=(128,128))
    img_arr = img_to_array(img)
    dataset[i] = img_arr

np.random.shuffle(dataset) #3

dshape = dataset.shape
print("dataset shape ", dshape)


pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler()), ('pca', PCA(n_components=5))])

pipeline.fit_transform(dataset)
```

i am currently getting an error

this is my output print out with the error

```
dataset shape  (9171, 128, 128, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "embedder1_main.py", line 78, in <module>
    pipeline.fit_transform(dataset)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 426, in fit_transform
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 348, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 847, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 806, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 841, in partial_fit
    X = self._validate_data(
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 561, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_params)
  File "/Users/james/miniforge3/envs/konstant-3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 786, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found array with dim 4. StandardScaler expected <= 2.
```

what is causing this error and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As the print output states, your dataset shape is `(9171, 128, 128, 3)` so `dim = 4`.

The code in the link you provided uses deep neural networks to train a model giving the author the chance to work with multi-band images (RGB) with ease.
Also, to work with values between 0 and 1, the author divides the image array by 255 (the maximum possible value).

If you still want to use `StandardScaler`, I'm afraid that you will need a custom function that process each image and each band separately so it is able to process a `(128,128)` array each time, although I'm not sure is the best approach.